# Configure Bootstrap Sass variables with @use while making bootstrap members available in current module

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass

I want to **configure [Bootstrap 4's Sass files](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/theming/) with my own variables and then be able to import all Bootstrap's configured members in other sass files** (and using WebPack `:export{}` magic).

I'd usually go with declaring my variables and then throwing a `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"` in it like:

```
$primary: #eee;
$body-color: $primary;
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
:export{ primary: $primary; body-color: $body-color;}
```

but as [Sass doc mentions](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import):

> The Sass team discourages the continued use of the @import rule. Sass will gradually phase it out over the next few years, and eventually remove it from the language entirely. Prefer the @use rule instead.

### @use with ():

With [`@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#configuration) variables marked as `!default` are overridable by adding `with ($variable: value)` **but** you have to write the `@use` directive on top of your file (prior declaring any variable that you could configure it with). Best I could go with it would be:

```
@use "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap" with (primary: #eee, body-color: #eee);
:export{ primary: bootstrap.$primary; body-color: bootstrap.$body-color;}
```

Pretty straightforward **but** I can't share values between configured variables and Bootstrap's members aren't exported from the file! (instead of declaring `#eee` for multiple variables I'd like them to share a variable holding this value).

### meta.load-css($url, $with):

Another approach would be to use the sass' meta mixin [`meta.load-css`](https://sasscss.org/documentation/modules/meta#load-css) that permits you to load and configure a module without being restricted to do it atop of the file. (And being able to declare variables prior to it) **but** this come at the expense of NOT loading any loaded module's member:

> This doesn’t make any members from the loaded module available in the current module.

### with mixins

[Sass' documentation mentions](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#with-mixins) the use of mixins to configure an imported module more thoroughly, I couldn't really understand how I could achieve that by reading their example, maybe that would be a working solution?

### Question:

**SO, how could I configure Bootstrap Sass files with shared overriding variables (in the load configuration, exported from the module and export through Webpack)?** Is that even possible?

Comment: Wow I was not aware, that @use is around that long ... i do have the exact same problem, years later. Did you come up with something that worked for you?

Comment: Hey @denns, unfortunately for this problem I don't think I did, every option had cons but in the end the deprecation notice didn't mean we couldn't stick to the previous version and just ignore it, so we did!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I have to deal with this anyway, cause the team switch most of the project to `@use` anyway. I will solve this by keeping the variables twice and somehow try to use `@warn` when `sass:meta`-function `variable-exists` fails for some of the variables. Would be so much easier if all of this could be used with a normal sass-map ... ‍♂️